# confused about reactjs lifecycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following Sharepoint Framework webpart, which basically renders a grid depending on a dropdown property which has the list names.

```tsx
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDom from "react-dom";
import { Version } from "@microsoft/sp-core-library";
import {
  BaseClientSideWebPart,
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField,
  PropertyPaneDropdown,
  IPropertyPaneDropdownOption,
  IPropertyPaneField,
  PropertyPaneLabel
} from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";

import * as strings from "FactoryMethodWebPartStrings";
import FactoryMethod from "./components/FactoryMethod";
import { IFactoryMethodProps } from "./components/IFactoryMethodProps";
import { IFactoryMethodWebPartProps } from "./IFactoryMethodWebPartProps";
import * as lodash from "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset";
import List from "./components/models/List";
import { Environment, EnvironmentType } from "@microsoft/sp-core-library";
import IDataProvider from "./components/dataproviders/IDataProvider";
import MockDataProvider from "./test/MockDataProvider";
import SharePointDataProvider from "./components/dataproviders/SharepointDataProvider";

export default class FactoryMethodWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IFactoryMethodWebPartProps> {
  private _dropdownOptions: IPropertyPaneDropdownOption[];
  private _selectedList: List;
  private _disableDropdown: boolean;
  private _dataProvider: IDataProvider;
  private _factorymethodContainerComponent: FactoryMethod;

  protected onInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.context.statusRenderer.displayLoadingIndicator(this.domElement, "Todo");

    /*
    Create the appropriate data provider depending on where the web part is running.
    The DEBUG flag will ensure the mock data provider is not bundled with the web part when you package the
     solution for distribution, that is, using the --ship flag with the package-solution gulp command.
    */
    if (DEBUG && Environment.type === EnvironmentType.Local) {
      this._dataProvider = new MockDataProvider();
    } else {
      this._dataProvider = new SharePointDataProvider();
      this._dataProvider.webPartContext = this.context;
    }

    this.openPropertyPane = this.openPropertyPane.bind(this);

    /*
    Get the list of tasks lists from the current site and populate the property pane dropdown field with the values.
    */
    this.loadLists()
      .then(() => {
        /*
         If a list is already selected, then we would have stored the list Id in the associated web part property.
         So, check to see if we do have a selected list for the web part. If we do, then we set that as the selected list
         in the property pane dropdown field.
        */
        if (this.properties.spListIndex) {
          this.setSelectedList(this.properties.spListIndex.toString());
          this.context.statusRenderer.clearLoadingIndicator(this.domElement);
        }
      });

    return super.onInit();
  }

  // render method of the webpart, actually calls Component
  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IFactoryMethodProps > = React.createElement(
      FactoryMethod,
      {
        spHttpClient: this.context.spHttpClient,
        siteUrl: this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl,
        listName: this._dataProvider.selectedList === undefined ? "GenericList" : this._dataProvider.selectedList.Title,
        dataProvider: this._dataProvider,
        configureStartCallback: this.openPropertyPane
      }
    );

    // reactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
    this._factorymethodContainerComponent = <FactoryMethod>ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);

  }

  // loads lists from the site and fill the dropdown.
  private loadLists(): Promise<any> {
    return this._dataProvider.getLists()
      .then((lists: List[]) => {
        // disable dropdown field if there are no results from the server.
        this._disableDropdown = lists.length === 0;
        if (lists.length !== 0) {
          this._dropdownOptions = lists.map((list: List) => {
            return {
              key: list.Id,
              text: list.Title
            };
          });
        }
      });
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse("1.0");
  }

  protected onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath: string, oldValue: any, newValue: any): void {
    /*
    Check the property path to see which property pane feld changed. If the property path matches the dropdown, then we set that list
    as the selected list for the web part.
    */
    if (propertyPath === "spListIndex") {
      this.setSelectedList(newValue);
    }

    /*
    Finally, tell property pane to re-render the web part.
    This is valid for reactive property pane.
    */
    super.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath, oldValue, newValue);
  }

  // sets the selected list based on the selection from the dropdownlist
  private setSelectedList(value: string): void {
    const selectedIndex: number = lodash.findIndex(this._dropdownOptions,
      (item: IPropertyPaneDropdownOption) => item.key === value
    );

    const selectedDropDownOption: IPropertyPaneDropdownOption = this._dropdownOptions[selectedIndex];

    if (selectedDropDownOption) {
      this._selectedList = {
        Title: selectedDropDownOption.text,
        Id: selectedDropDownOption.key.toString()
      };

      this._dataProvider.selectedList = this._selectedList;
    }
  }


  // we add fields dynamically to the property pane, in this case its only the list field which we will render
  private getGroupFields(): IPropertyPaneField<any>[] {
    const fields: IPropertyPaneField<any>[] = [];

    // we add the options from the dropdownoptions variable that was populated during init to the dropdown here.
    fields.push(PropertyPaneDropdown("spListIndex", {
      label: "Select a list",
      disabled: this._disableDropdown,
      options: this._dropdownOptions
    }));

    /*
    When we do not have any lists returned from the server, we disable the dropdown. If that is the case,
    we also add a label field displaying the appropriate message.
    */
    if (this._disableDropdown) {
      fields.push(PropertyPaneLabel(null, {
        text: "Could not find tasks lists in your site. Create one or more tasks list and then try using the web part."
      }));
    }

    return fields;
  }

  private openPropertyPane(): void {
    this.context.propertyPane.open();
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              /*
              Instead of creating the fields here, we call a method that will return the set of property fields to render.
              */
              groupFields: this.getGroupFields()
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

my component.tsx

```
//#region Imports
import * as React from "react";
import styles from "./FactoryMethod.module.scss";
import  { IFactoryMethodProps } from "./IFactoryMethodProps";
import {
  IDetailsListItemState,
  IDetailsNewsListItemState,
  IDetailsDirectoryListItemState,
  IDetailsAnnouncementListItemState,
  IFactoryMethodState
} from "./IFactoryMethodState";
import { IListItem } from "./models/IListItem";
import { IAnnouncementListItem } from "./models/IAnnouncementListItem";
import { INewsListItem } from "./models/INewsListItem";
import { IDirectoryListItem } from "./models/IDirectoryListItem";
import { escape } from "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset";
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http";
import { ListItemFactory} from "./ListItemFactory";
import { TextField } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField";
import {
  DetailsList,
  DetailsListLayoutMode,
  Selection,
  buildColumns,
  IColumn
} from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/DetailsList";
import { MarqueeSelection } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/MarqueeSelection";
import { autobind } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Utilities";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
//#endregion


export default class FactoryMethod extends React.Component<IFactoryMethodProps, IFactoryMethodState> {
  constructor(props: IFactoryMethodProps, state: any) {
    super(props);
    this.setInitialState();
  }

  // lifecycle help here: https://staminaloops.github.io/undefinedisnotafunction/understanding-react/

  //#region Mouting events lifecycle

  // the data returned from render is neither a string nor a DOM node.
  // it's a lightweight description of what the DOM should look like.
  // inspects this.state and this.props and create the markup.
  // when your data changes, the render method is called again.
  // react diff the return value from the previous call to render with
  // the new one, and generate a minimal set of changes to be applied to the DOM.
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IFactoryMethodProps> {
    switch(this.props.listName) {
        case "GenericList":
          // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
          return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsListItemState.items} columns={this.state.columns} />;
        case "News":
          // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
          return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsNewsListItemState.items} columns={this.state.columns}/>;
        case "Announcements":
          // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
          return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsAnnouncementListItemState.items} columns={this.state.columns}/>;
        case "Directory":
          // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
          return <this.ListMarqueeSelection items={this.state.DetailsDirectoryListItemState.items} columns={this.state.columns}/>;
        default:
          return null;
    }
  }

   // invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately AFTER the initial rendering occurs.
   public componentDidMount(): void {
    // you can access any refs to your children
    // (e.g., to access the underlying DOM representation - ReactDOM.findDOMNode).
    // the componentDidMount() method of child components is invoked before that of parent components.
    // if you want to integrate with other JavaScript frameworks,
    // set timers using setTimeout or setInterval,
    // or send AJAX requests, perform those operations in this method.
    this._configureWebPart = this._configureWebPart.bind(this);
    this.readItemsAndSetStatus("");
  }

  //#endregion

  //#region Props changes lifecycle events (after a property changes from parent component)
  public componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: IFactoryMethodProps): void {
    if(nextProps.listName !== this.props.listName) {
      this.readItemsAndSetStatus(nextProps.listName);
    }
  }

  //#endregion

  //#region private methods
  private _configureWebPart(): void {
    this.props.configureStartCallback();
  }

  public setInitialState(): void {
    this.state = {
      type: "ListItem",
      status: this.listNotConfigured(this.props)
        ? "Please configure list in Web Part properties"
        : "Ready",
      columns:[],
      DetailsListItemState:{
        items:[]
      },
      DetailsNewsListItemState:{
        items:[]
      },
      DetailsDirectoryListItemState:{
        items:[]
      },
      DetailsAnnouncementListItemState:{
        items:[]
      },
    };
  }

  // reusable inline component
  private ListMarqueeSelection = (itemState: {columns: IColumn[], items: IListItem[] }) => (
      <div>
          <DetailsList
            items={ itemState.items }
            columns={ itemState.columns }
            setKey="set"
            layoutMode={ DetailsListLayoutMode.fixedColumns }
            selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={ true }
            compact={ true }>
          </DetailsList>
      </div>
  )

  // read items using factory method pattern and sets state accordingly
  private readItemsAndSetStatus(nextListName: string): void {
    this.setState({
      status: "Loading all items..."
    });

    const factory: ListItemFactory = new ListItemFactory();
    factory.getItems(this.props.spHttpClient, this.props.siteUrl, nextListName)
    .then((items: any[]) => {
      const keyPart: string = this.props.listName === "GenericList" ? "" : nextListName;
        // the explicit specification of the type argument `keyof {}` is bad and
        // it should not be required.
        this.setState<keyof {}>({
          status: `Successfully loaded ${items.length} items`,
          ["Details" + keyPart + "ListItemState"] : {
            items
          },
          columns: buildColumns(items)
        });
    });
  }

  private listNotConfigured(props: IFactoryMethodProps): boolean {
    return props.listName === undefined ||
      props.listName === null ||
      props.listName.length === 0;
  }

  //#endregion
}
```

and my factory object

```
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http";
import { IWebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";
import { IListItem} from "./models/IListItem";
import { IFactory } from "./IFactory";
import { INewsListItem } from "./models/INewsListItem";
import { IDirectoryListItem } from "./models/IDirectoryListItem";
import { IAnnouncementListItem } from "./models/IAnnouncementListItem";

export class ListItemFactory implements IFactory {
    private _listItems: IListItem[];
    public getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: string): Promise<IListItem[]> {
        if(listName === ""){
            listName = "GenericList";
        }
        switch(listName) {
            case "GenericList":
                let items: IListItem[];
                // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json(); 
                })
                .then((json: { value: IListItem[] }) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(json.value));
                    return items=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        { 
                            //key: v.id,
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title                        
                        }
                    ));
                });  
            case "News":
                let newsitems: INewsListItem[];
                // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,Created By,Modified By,newsheader,newsbody,expiryDate`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: INewsListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((json: { value: INewsListItem[] }) => {
                    return items=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        { 
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                            newsheader: v.newsheader,
                            newsbody: v.newsbody,
                            expiryDate: v.expiryDate
                        }
                    ));
                });
            case "Announcements":
                let announcementitems: IAnnouncementListItem[];
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IAnnouncementListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((json: { value: IAnnouncementListItem[] }) => {
                    return items=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        { 
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                            announcementBody: v.announcementBody,
                            expiryDate: v.expiryDate
                        }
                    ));
                });
            case "Directory":
                let directoryitems: IDirectoryListItem[];
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IDirectoryListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((json: { value: IDirectoryListItem[] }) => {
                    return items=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        { 
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title,
                            firstName: v.firstName,
                            lastName: v.lastName,
                            mobileNumber: v.mobileNumber,
                            internalNumber: v.internalNumber
                        }
                    ));
                });
            default:
            // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json(); 
                })
                .then((json: { value: IListItem[] }) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(json.value));
                    return items=json.value.map((v,i)=>(
                        { 
                            //key: v.id,
                            id: v.Id,
                            title: v.Title,
                            created: v.Created,
                            createdby: v.Author.Title,
                            modified: v.Modified,
                            modifiedby: v.Editor.Title                        
                        }
                    ));
                }); 
            }
      }
}
```

The problem is that the first time it renders, the listname is undefined, so it reads data from the GenericList and I can see the grid rendered which is desired behavior

But whenever I select another list, I get an empty string as parameter on the getlistitems parameter, its not taking either Announcements, News, etc

What am I missing here?

Comment: React docs are a good source to clear all the confusion about lifecycle functions.Check this out https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: Consider reworking the readItemsAndSetStatus function to use only on setState call as these calls are async.

Comment: I dont understand, how would you do it?

Comment: If you add a `console.log()` of the `listName` prop that is passed to the React app during `FactoryMethodWebPart.render()`, what is the console output after making some dropdown selections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Note: I do not use the SharePoint framework.

I believe your issue lies in the integration between the SharePoint framework `WebPart` and React. You don't see a change in the React app after the dropdown selection because the React app never receives a change in its properties.

There are two options:

1) Manually call `FactoryMethodWebPart.render()` when the dropdown changes during the `setSelectedList()`. Since I do not use the SharePoint framework, I do not know if this is best practice. I do know that this would re-build the React app and insert it into the DOM again instead of triggering a re-render.

2) Use a higher order component that allows you to pass new props to the already built React app. This solution is based on [this article](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/react-the-powerful-higher-order-component-pattern). Idea is to build a function that returns a wrapper around a Component. This function accepts both the Component to render and a `subscribe` function that in turn accepts the function that can be used to pass new props to the component. When the Component is created, it calls the `subscribe()` method, and simply renders the Component passed to it.

The HOC:

```
const connect = (Component, subscribe) => class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const rerender = props => this.setState(props);
    subscribe(rerender);
  }

  render() {
    const props = { ...this.props, ...this.state };
    return <Component {...props} />;
  }
}
```

The use case:

```
export default class FactoryMethodWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IFactoryMethodWebPartProps> {
  // other private fields
  private _factoryMethodComponent;
  private _setFactoryMethodProps;

  protected onInit(): Promise<void> {
    // ...
    this._factoryMethodComponent = connect(FactoryMethod, rerender => this._setFactoryMethodProps = rerender);
  }

  public render(): void {
    const element = React.createElement(
      this._factoryMethodComponent, // use the connected component instead of FactoryMethod
      { ... }
  ]  );

    this._factorymethodContainerComponent = ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  private setSelectedList(value: string): void {
    // ...

    this._setFactoryMethodProps({ listName: selectedDropDownOption ? selectedDropDownOption.text : 'GenericList' });
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use <!-- language: lang-tsx --> to format the code